# serialize object so that State<string,object> doesn't launch an exception

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, serialization

I have an object and am trying to save it to the State dictionary, but when i pass an object to it using :

```
State["name"] = object;
```

i see some exceptions being raised:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

State does automatically serialize and deserialize for objects passed. What could be the problem?

I suspect that the object must use [Serialize] when the class is declared. i try to use [Serialize] on my class but it isn't recognized although i have `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` declared and the reference exists

**UPDATE**

here is the class that i'm trying to serialize :

```
public class MeshObject
    {
        public ModelMesh mesh; // xna specific class
        public Matrix startOrientation; // xna specific class
        public Matrix Orientation; // xna specific class
        public bool isSetInPlace = false;
        public bool isSelected = false;
        public bool inPlay = false;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

from what i understand from this  [post](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/40747.aspx), there is no [Serializable] in Silverlight. How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Does the type contain other non-serializable types? Please post the code!

Comment: ModelMesh is not serializable... Mark the mesh field as [XmlIgnore] and see what happens. (Make sure the MeshObject class is marked as Serializable)

Comment: @Erno i can't mark MeshObject as Serializable. I have all the references and the compiler can't recognize my [Serializable] tag

Comment: @Erno there seems to not be [Serializable] in Silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can [read here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/a471c796-56ec-4b43-bcd6-e1f3c2e518e8)

- The Serializable attribute is not available in WP7 (it is only needed for binary serialization anyway)
- You can use XmlSerializer to Serialize and Deserialize
- You'll need to reference the  "System.Xml.Serialization.dll" too.

If you want to serialize a type that is not serializable you will need to implement the serialization yourself: http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-7-serialization

Comment: your way is good but i ended using [DataContract] and [DataMember] for my class and it worked as well.

Comment: Yes, that is an alternative that is mentioned in the article I linked to.